# function st_distancespheroid(geometry, geometry) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have installed postgis, I still have problem:

> function st_distancespheroid(geometry, geometry) does not exist

```
    WITH data AS (
    SELECT a.*,
    CAST(ST_DistanceSpheroid(geometry(location), st_geomfromtext('POINT(' || $7::decimal || ' ' || $8::decimal || ')', 4326))as numeric) / 1000 AS distance
    FROM agent AS a
    WHERE (a.agent_code ILIKE $1
    OR a.name ILIKE $1
    OR a.phone LIKE $1)
    AND
    a.sub_district_name LIKE ANY(string_to_array($4, ','))
    AND
    a.agent_status_id LIKE ANY(string_to_array($5, ','))
    AND CASE WHEN $6 = 'FAVORITE' THEN
    a.is_subscription = true
    WHEN $6 = 'REGULER' THEN
    a.is_subscription != true
    ELSE
    a.location LIKE '%%'
    END
    ORDER BY distance ASC
),
data_counter AS (
    SELECT COUNT(agent_id) AS __total__
    FROM data
)
SELECT * 
FROM data, data_counter
LIMIT $2
OFFSET $3
`
```

when I run my go repo

Comment: Installing is not enough, have you [enabled](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_administration.html#create_spatial_db) it for your database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### How to install PostGIS

After installation you have to create the extension in the database. For instance, to install PostGIS 3.0 in a Debian distribution running PostgreSQL 13:

```
apt-get install postgresql-13-postgis-3
```

After that you create the extension in the database

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Now you'll be able to use the spatial functions.

##### How to calculate distances over a spheroid / sphere

The function [`ST_DistanceSpheroid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html) expects three parameters, namely two geometries and the shperoid. In your code you're calling the function using only two geometries, hence the error `function st_distancespheroid(geometry, geometry) does not exist`. This is how it should be called (adapt it to the spheroid of your choice):

```
SELECT
  ST_DistanceSpheroid(geom1,geom2,'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')
FROM t;
```

You can also tell [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) to compute the distances using the spheroid if you cast the `geometry` parameters to `geography`:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(geom1::geography,geom2::geography,true) FROM t;
```

Another option - less accurate - is to use [`ST_DistanceSphere`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html):

```
 SELECT ST_DistanceSphere(geom1,geom2) FROM t;
```

Comment: i have install postgis-3 but still not work

Comment: @TommyFerdianHadimarta how did you install it? have you created the extension afterwards?

Comment: i have install it form stack builder 
3.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: @TommyFerdianHadimarta did you create the extension afterwards?

Comment: i did it
extension "postgis" already exists

Comment: @TommyFerdianHadimarta wait a minute: you're using the functio ST_DistanceSpheroid wrong. You're missing the spheroid (3rd parameter): e.g. `'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'`